# Phpspreadsheet how to set autoheight for merged cell?

Tags: php, excel, styles, office365, phpspreadsheet

`setWrapText` work well for one cell, but not works for merged cell.

Here is the code I use to set autosize for merged cell, but it not works.

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->fromArray([["1\n1\n2\n\n3\n"],range(1,3),['188196','test']]);
$sheet->mergeCells('A1:D1');
$sheet->getStyle("A1:D1")->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```

unmerged cell:
[image]

merged cell:
[image]

Comment: Have you figured out a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must set a rowhight by calculation. See this [article](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-a-rows-height). You could try

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('10')->setRowHeight(-1);
```

to get the autoheight value.

-1 is the value of auto height. Means the value will calculated automatically. If you need a number of height. I would suggest to calc the height over the value of the cell. You must do following: Find newlines in the content and multiply them with 12.75 pts (standard height).