# Get calculated height of a PHPSpreadsheet row

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to get the calculated height of a row in [`PHPSpreadsheet`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) but whenever I do something like

```php
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($row)->getRowHeight();
```

I always get a `-1` value which is correct based on their documentation as that is the default value. I need to get the calculated height in `pt` though as I need to do some calculations. I have a cell that is set to wrap text, and spans multiple lines. Anyone knows how to get the calculated height of a row?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to fix the same issue as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858786/phpspreadsheet-how-to-set-autoheight-for-merged-cell

Answer (score 0):

-1 is the value of auto height. Means the value will calculated automatically. If you need a number of height. I would suggest to calc the height over the value of the cell. You must do following: Find newlines in the content and multiply them with 12.75 pts (standard height).  Some informations you can find [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-a-rows-height) to.

Comment: There's usually no new lines in the content because the cell is set to wrap text and has a set width. The content is a single line of long text.

Comment: Then the answer is 12.75 pts line height.

Comment: No that's the height of a row for a single line. I have a single line of text but the cell is set to wrap text when it gets too long so even the single line text will span multiple lines if they are long enough. How many lines it would take, that I wouldn't know.